# How to import batch filename in batch file

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have a batch file that setups something I made.
In the batch file I have a variable called OriginalFileName and set it to ProgramSetup,

```
set OriginalFileName=ProgramSetup
```

I want to know how to import the current filename of the batch file to CurrentFileName to later on check if the filename was changed or not with:

```
if "%CurrentFileName%" EQU "%OriginalFileName%" goto :anything
```

if not .... [other actions]

So my question is: How to import the current filename of a batch file to a variable when the batch file is running.

Comment: Do you really mean 'when the batch file is running'? Could you not check this at the start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `%0` for the current script, or more commonly:

- `%~dp0` for the drive:\path,
- `%~nx0` for the filename.ext

Comment: Thanks, I will check it when I get to my Laptop.

Comment: grawity is correct - [learning about arguments](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) opens up a whole bunch of different options when you're working through cmd.exe and batch; definitely worth exploring.